# cancelling tasks with cancellation tokens

Tags: c#, task, cancellationtokensource

I have a task which gets my data. I have another property that if changed cancels the Task and starts the Task again but with a different parameter shown  below.

```
private CancellationTokenSource CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

private void LoadMyStuff(string parameter)
{          
     Task<List<Stuff>> loadStuff = new Task<List<Stuff>>(() => ServiceMethod(parameter));
     loadStuff.Start();
     loadStuff.ContinueWith((Sender) =>
     {
           foreach (var entry in Sender.Result)
           {
               if (!CTS.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   //Proccess my data      
               }
               else
               {
                   CTS.Cancel();
                   return;
               }
            }
     }, CTS.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
     loadStuff.ContinueWith((Sender) =>
     {
          //Clean Up
     }, CTS.Token, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
 }
```

Property:

```
private Thing _myThing
public Thing MyThing
{
   get { return _myThing; }
   set 
     {
        _myThing= value;
        CTS.Cancel();
        LoadMyStuff(parameter); 
     }
}
```

So my problem is I am always cancelling the task before it even completes in this instance. How do I get this scenario where the first instance of the task cancels but the second fired from the `MyThing` property runs through to completion?

Comment: If I understood you right you should create a new CanceletionTokenSource for every task.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by each 'batch' of tasks?

Comment: @user1 Nevermind that, I thought you were creating a `List<Task<Stuff>>`, and not a `Task<List<Stuff>>`. Ivan was right.

Comment: You need to use the `CancellationToken` inside of `Task` rather than using `CancellationTokenSource`. Otherwise you have a race condition (i.e) When you call `CTS.Cancel();` and set `CTS = new ..` your old tasks may be/ maynot be cancelled because new `CTS.IsCancellationRequested` will be false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new `CancellationTokenSource`.

Once a `CancellationTokenSource` is signaled, all its token will be signaled as well, and they'll remain that way.
So if you want to start a new task, you need a brand new token source.

Comment: so if I understand this correctly in my `MyThing` property should I do `CTS.Cancel();` then `CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();` then `LoadMyStuff();`?

Comment: @user1 That's one possible solution, but I don't like that design. Think responsibilities. It's not `MyThing`'s responsibility to reset the token source. I think `LoadMyStuff` should be the one resetting the token source when the method starts.